# No internet through OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, firewall, iptables, openvpn

I am having trouble with my OpenVPN setup. I have a Linode box with an OpenVPN server installed on it and I managed to get Tunnelblick to establish a vpn connection from my mac. I followed this guide to do the setup (https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/vpn/secure-communications-with-openvpn-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-and-debian-7)

The problem is that I lose internet access when I connect to the VPN. I'm not very familiar with iptables but I'm fairly certain that it's a firewall problem on the linode box.

I uncommented the REJECT directives in iptables and the internet started to work, but now my linode is unprotected. I'd appreciate some help with my setup. Here's how my iptable configuration file looks right now.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Wed Sep 17 20:16:01 2014
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [655071:117449311]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [531569:271562663]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep 17 20:16:01 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Wed Sep 17 20:16:01 2014
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [655387:117519098]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [531569:271562663]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep 17 20:16:01 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Wed Sep 17 20:16:01 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1779:93936]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1778:93888]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10:616]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [10:616]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep 17 20:16:01 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Wed Sep 17 20:16:01 2014
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [333602:56545923]
:INPUT ACCEPT [333602:56545923]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [269675:131489507]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [269675:131489507]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep 17 20:16:01 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Wed Sep 17 20:16:01 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# -A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -i lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8484 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 52698 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3001 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 943 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
# -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap+ -j ACCEPT
# -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tap+ -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Notice that the following lines are commented out and shouldn't be:

```
# -A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -i lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
# -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
# -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

EDIT:
Output of sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Output of iptables-save:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Sat Sep 20 03:41:08 2014
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [14181206:2321341249]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [454424:378929599]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [11546594:6308759963]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 20 03:41:08 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Sat Sep 20 03:41:08 2014
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [14635663:2700275174]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [11546595:6308760175]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 20 03:41:08 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Sat Sep 20 03:41:08 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1875725:100410074]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1866676:99465105]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [20810:1333821]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [20816:1334245]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 20 03:41:08 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Sat Sep 20 03:41:08 2014
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [14635664:2700275226]
:INPUT ACCEPT [14181207:2321341301]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [454424:378929599]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [11546600:6308761475]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [12001024:6687691074]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 20 03:41:08 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Sat Sep 20 03:41:08 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [5701:859812]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8484 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 52698 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3001 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 943 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tap+ -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: What is the output of `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`? Oh yeah, and while we’re at it, also post the output of `iptables-save`. It will be very similar to what is already there, but probably not the same.

Comment: Just added the outputs.

Comment: Seems to be OK. You could inspect further with `tcpdump`, a useful tool for traffic analysis. Use it like `tcpdump -i eth0` (also look at `tun0` or whatever your VPN interface is). Next, remove *all* IPTables rules. [This](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html) is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to turn off iptables?
Although the rules seem fine, you should try turning off your firewall.

I found this [script](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/openvpn-setup-script-for-debian-and-ubuntu/) to install and configure OpenVPN on an Ubuntu VPS. It works.

Comment: Well, at least without `iptables`, it is guaranteed *not* to work. ;) `MASQUERADE`/`SNAT` is required.

Comment: @DanielB, oh my... thank you so much for this comment. In my case, I had the firewall turned off just for the first test, but it was not working. I had a script prepared to turn the firewall on (with the masquerade and everything) but I had not applied because I was still testing. I was going crazy trying to figure out why it was not working. When I saw your comment everything clicked in my head. Thanks (even though you posted this 6 years ago).